# Is levomenthol superior to Menthol as a pain killer in humans and what are the ways to determine this?

Tags: medicinal-chemistry

I desire to learn whether levomenthol is superior to Menthol as a pain killer in humans.

I didn't find a wiki article about levomenthol and the article [Menthol](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Menthol&oldid=936768369) doesn't mention this molecule.

The chemical formulas are the same but I understand that the only difference is the spatial position of chemical bonds between the atoms, as can be learnt in pubchem:

- https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Menthol
- https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/l-Menthol

### My problem

I don't know what are the main ways for chemists to decide which one should work better in humans but hope for a simple explanation for non chemists.

I thought about this after reading that *Strepsils*, the famous British sore throat lozenges, contain levomenthol.

I think about this because I know some other medicines are "levo" versions of others (for example, cetrizine and levocetrizine).

### My question

Is levomenthol superior to Menthol as pain killer in humans and what are the ways to determine this?

Comment: Oookay, I can see you try there, but menthol isn't exactly a painkiller and l- (levo) is just a description of isomer, another being d-  (dextro)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dextrorotation_and_levorotation

Comment: @Mithoron Here is a starting point to read on the analgesic properties of menthol, and the channel it binds to: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29524352

Comment: Another paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6600640/

Comment: @KarstenTheis Tell that to House M.D. Strepsils isn't exactly Vicodin.